# Error in data.frame(cong = subset(df, congruency == "congruent")$resp.rt * : arguments imply differing number of rows: 2530, 2510

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio

I'm having trouble generating a graph of "incongruent" and "congruent" stroop task data.  I keep getting the error message above.  Below is the code I used to attempt to generate a plot:

````
    ```{r echo=FALSE}
    ################################################################
    plotStroopLin <- function(tmp, mainTitle = "Stroop (1935) Fig. 1") {
    # calculate the break points for the histograms
    bkmin <- min(tmp$cong, tmp$incong)
    bkmax <- max(tmp$cong, tmp$incong)
    bkmin <- (floor(bkmin / 10) * 10) - 10
    bkmax <- (ceiling(bkmax / 10) * 10) + 10
    bks <- seq(bkmin, bkmax, 10)

    # compute histogram of congruent RT
    h1 <- hist(tmp$cong, plot = FALSE, breaks = bks)
    # compute incongruent RT histogram
    h2 <- hist(tmp$incong, plot = FALSE, breaks = bks)

    pltmax.y <- max(h1$counts, h2$counts) * 1.1
    plot(h1$counts ~ h1$breaks[1:length(h1$breaks)-1],
         type = "s",
         lwd = 2,
         col = "red",
         xlim = c(0, 300),
         ylim = c(0, pltmax.y),
         xlab = "Seconds per Hundred Reactions",
         ylab = "Frequency",
         main = mainTitle)
    abline(h=0)

    # compute mean and sd for the Gaussian
    mu1 <- mean(tmp$cong)
    sd1 <- sd(tmp$cong)
    x1 <- seq(mu1 - 3 * sd1, mu1 + 3 * sd1, by = 0.1)
    y1 <- dnorm(x1, mu1, sd1)
    y1 <- y1 * max(h1$counts) / max(y1)
    lines(y1 ~ x1, col = "red")
    lines(c(mu1, mu1), c(0, max(y1)), col = "red")

    # add incongruent RT histogram
    h2 <- hist(tmp$incong, plot = FALSE, breaks = bks)
    points(h2$counts ~ h2$breaks[1:length(h2$breaks)-1],
           type = "s",
           lwd = 2,
           col = "blue")

    # compute mean and sd for the Gaussian
    mu2 <- mean(tmp$incong)
    sd2 <- sd(tmp$incong)
    x2 <- seq(mu2 - 3 * sd2, mu2 + 3 * sd2, by = 0.1)
    y2 <- dnorm(x2, mu2, sd2)
    y2 <- y2 * (max(h2$counts) / max(y2)) * (sd1 / sd2)
    lines(y2 ~ x2, col = "blue")
    lines(c(mu2, mu2), c(0, max(y2)), col = "blue")
}    

# use the mean RT of each subject
plot.Stroop1 <- function() {
    # use all individual data
    tmp <- data.frame(cong = subset(df, congruency == "congruent")$resp.rt * 100, 
                      incong = subset(df, congruency == "incongruent")$resp.rt * 100)
    plotStroopLin(tmp, "All Reaction Times")
}
```
````

I then used the following code to attempt to actually visualize the plot:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, fig.width = 7, fig.height = 5, fig.cap="Stroop (1935, Figure 1"}
plot.Stroop1()
```
````

After attempting to run this specific chunk, I received the error code in the title... am I missing something? I am unsure if the error is occurring because I need to do something with the data file.  The rows end at 5041. Any help would be so greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Your example is clearly not minimal. [mcve]. I suppose the two subsets `subset(df, congruency == "congruent")` and `subset(df, congruency == "incongruent")` have different numbers of rows.

Comment: Eventually helps: in your function `plot.Stroop1()` do `tmp <- list(cong=..., incong=...)`